# Extract audio stream of a .ts file onto a different format

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a .ts audio file and I want to convert it to a .wav file without losing quality.

This is what I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.ts -vn -acodec copy audio.wav
```

This does return a .wav file, but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is optimal or if there's anything I can do to end up with a file of better quality. Unfortunately there are many formats such as .aac that I can't work with.

Lastly, although this returns a .wav file, it is pretty buggy. It won't play with the windows player, and the only way to listen to it will be by dragging it onto a browser. If I try to advance the audio it will cut off immediately, and it will also not replay unless I refresh the page. 
I'm assuming these problems have to do with the way I'm converting it, but I don't know how to avoid them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

WAVs typically contain uncompressed audio. So, unless your source audio is uncompressed, you have to decode it first.

So,

```
ffmpeg -i audio.ts -vn audio.wav
```

This will decode the audio and then encode it using the default encoder for WAV which is signed PCM 16-bit.

Comment: I was under the impression that doing this would lose audio quality. Is that not the case?

Comment: Any compressed audio has to be decoded to an uncompressed form in order to be played. This command stores that form into a file.

Comment: Then, in other words, it is losing audio quality, right? I don't need to end up with a .wav file, it can be another format if the result will be better. How could I convert it into a different file that won't lose any quality at all?

Comment: No, there is no loss in quality as long as the audio isn't downsampled or has its bit depth reduced. The compressed stream isn't audio - it's a coded format. The decoded and uncompressed form is audio data.

Comment: Is that so? Because if I use a program like spek to visualize the audio spectrum, I see that the lows reach a lot further in the .wav file. Should I not worry about that?

Comment: Spek uses ffmpeg to decode audio. It's likely using a float point decode format for analysis.

Comment: If you know the stream codec, you can just dump the coded form to a file.